# Windows Server 2003 / IIS: How do I set up a folder to run as a website?

Tags: windows-server-2003, website, iis

I am trying to install a open-source web help desk on my VMWare Server 2003 Enterprise Ed., and I have already set up the server with several roles (DNS, DHCP, AD, and App. Server).  In order to install the software, I need to set up the extracted folder as a web site in IIS, and then run the setup from there...can someone help me please?

I've also already attempted to set up a website in IIS; also attempted to set up a virtual directory; all of these have proven fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Put the extracted contents in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`. Run setup.

Side note: it's a really bad idea to run all of those services on one machine, especially an old 2003 server. 2003 is going End of Support in about a year.

Comment: Thanks MDMarra.  I'm actually just using this to test the program, but will be converting to a copy of Win Server 2008 once I can get this up and running.

Comment: After adding, how do I get to run the Setup.  I'm still unable to browse.  I'm a fairly new user of Win Server, and using VMWare to learn, but also trying to test this other program simultaneously before installing it on the actual company server.